# What is the way of sending viewModel events to the view? Like a one time action

Tags: flutter, events, mvvm, provider

I try to implement **MVVM** in my flutter project. And I use **Provider** to observe/watch the viewModel members, and to call any method I need from the view model. But **I don't know a proper way to send one tine actions from viewModel -> view**. Like an action, that needs to be done on the UI part, in order to separate UI from business logic. I fell there should be an observable like behavior, or something based on rx.

Maybe a stream of type void, but if I have 3 actions, I'll need 3 controllers, 3 public streams, and the view should listen on those. **Is there any simpler solution?**

```
  final StreamController<void> _hideSpinner = StreamController();
  Stream<void> get hideSpinnerStream => _hideSpinner.stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using flutter_bloc, and from there you can easily emit a state from the "view model", that is the bloc or the cubit. It is a different pattern but this is the way I solved the above question.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc